# When AngularJS controller meets postMessage events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, postmessage

I have the following code which uses AngularJS and a message listener: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/dulonehomu/2/edit?html,js,output):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="Name"><br>
    <br>
    <textarea id="myText" ng-model="Name"></textarea>
  </div>
  <br>
  <span id="fromQuery"></span>

  <script>
    var prefix = "pre-";
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      function render() {
        document.getElementById("fromQuery").innerHTML = prefix + $scope.Name  
      }

      $scope.Name = "John";

      $scope.$watch('Name', function() {
        render();
      })
    });

    function receiveMessage(event) {
      prefix = event.data;
    }

    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

AngularJS defines a controller, which permits of synchronising everything: any change to `input` or `textarea` will impact `input`, `textarea` and the `span`. I also have a global variable `prefix` which always adds a prefix to the content of `input` or `textarea` and display it in `span`.

What complicates the case is the listener. Another web page will send this web page new prefixes (sorry I could not show the test here). At the moment, once the page receives a new prefix, it cannot call `render` because of the function scope, as a consequence, `span` is not refreshed with the new prefix. What I want to realise is that, once the page receives a new prefix, it refreshes systematically the `span` with the new prefix.

Does anyone know how to realise this?

Comment: can you be more precise on your question. It confuses a lot

Comment: It is hard to show the interaction of two pages with JSBin. Except that, which part confuses you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angular script : using `$window`

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
        $scope.prefix = "abc";//if prefix needs to change dynamically why not add it to scope ?
        function render() {
            document.getElementById("fromQuery").innerHTML = $scope.prefix + $scope.Name
        }

        $scope.Name = "John";

        function receiveMessage(event) {
            console.log(event.detail); //just checking
            $scope.$apply(function(){          
                $scope.prefix = event.detail;
             })
            //$scope.prefix = event.detail;
        }

        $window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

        $scope.$watch('Name', function () {
            render();
        })
       $scope.$watch('prefix', function() {
        console.log('prefix changed');
       render();
       })
    });
```

html + script for testing

```
<button type='button' onclick="doo()">TEST</button>
```

-

```
function doo() {
    var event = new CustomEvent('message', {
            'detail' : 'MyNewPrefix'
        });
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

If this is not what you wanted please let us know.

Comment: It works... Just need to add `render()` in the end of `receiveMessage`...

Comment: @SoftTimur true.. but isn't it already in the the `$watch('name'..`  ?

Comment: What I want is, once we click on `TEST` button, it refreshes systematically with the new prefix...

Comment: @SoftTimur.. I see. I've updated the answer to use `$scope.$apply` and a watch on the `prefix`.. not just when it in `Name` change ..

Comment: I realise that if we remove `$scope.$apply`, it will not work. So what does `$scope.$apply` exactly do?

Comment: @SoftTimur... Sorry I don't know if I can give you the best answer..To my understanding it calls the `$scope.$digest()` is responsible for detecting/applying changes of  the scope. Since our change has occurred outside the `$scope`, an external event, we are manually calling `$apply()` saying our model has got some changes so just fire the `watchers` and propagate the changes.

Comment: I see... Thank you, here is the working [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/recunamifo/2/edit?html,js,output) as a record...